Ubuntu 24.04 How to remove a network interface (Netplan, Cloud init)
I have an interface I want to get rid of. The machine was a basic Ubuntu 24.04 install. I configured the static IP on eth0 as presented by the installer.
I saw no way in the installer to remove the other interface 'enP26388s1', it has the same MAC address and in the installer appeared to copy the static address.
After the installation I had a network interface called 'enP26388s1' set to DHCP. I didn't want this. So after seeing we are meant to use netplan, and it was a minimal install (no NetworkManager) I removed it from /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml, and ran netplan apply. This did seem to take the interface down.
I restarted the machine, and the interface came back - its not in 50-cloud-init.yaml any more.
I have removed cloud-init apt remove cloud-init.
I have downed the interface using sudo ip link set enP26388s1 down
I have tried to delete it with ip link delete enP26388s1 and got the answer RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
However on issuing ip link show its still there
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5e:0a:0c:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enP26388s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master eth0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5e:0a:0c:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enP26388p0s2

I have noticed this in the system list (should I delete the enP26388s1 entries, what created them?)
sysys-devices-LNXSYSTM:00-LN...-net-enP26388s1.device loaded active plugged
sys-devices-LNXSYSTM:00-LN...-net-eth0.device         loaded active plugged
sys-subsystem-net-devices-enP26388s1.device           loaded active plugged
sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device                 loaded active plugged
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service                  loaded active exited
systemd-networkd.service                              loaded active running
systemd-networkd.socket                               loaded active running
network-online.target                                 loaded active active
network-pre.target                                    loaded active active

How do I delete / remove this interface.
